# MaTeX text now appears with a white background and not a transparent one

Tags: matex

LaTeX typeset text in Mathetmatica v13 created using MaTeX v1.7.8 now appears with a white background instead of a transparent one on my machine (MacOS Monterey). I suspect it has something to do with pdflatex or ghostscript versions on my machine (that may have changed), but I don't know how to get the transparency back. Any help will be much appreciated.

I'm using pdflatex v3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022) and ghostscript v9.55.0

I post below the result of one of the examples shown in the documentation of MaTeX in Mathematica:

```
PieChart[<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3|>, ChartLabels -> Placed[Automatic, Automatic, MaTeX[#, FontSize -> 24] &]]
```

[image]

Comment: yes, something wrong with yoursetup. Works ok for me V 13.01  on windows 10. ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDoa8.png)

Comment: How about `ghostscript v9.54`?

Comment: also, try changing from pdflatex to lualatex. I do not expect this to make difference for you, but something to try.  `ConfigureMaTeX["pdfLaTeX" ->"C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\MiKTeX\\miktex\\bin\\x64\\lualatex.exe"];`  (need ofcourse to change the path in this example to point to correct one for your OS.)

Comment: This is probably a problem with your LaTeX base. Works ok for me with MMA 13.0.1 on Windows 10.

Comment: @E.Chan-López  Yes may be. on the mac there is different Latex distribution *MacTex*. On windows it is *MikTeX* and on linux, it is *TeXLive*  They all supposed to behave the same in theory since all packages and core tex is same. But that might not be the case all the time.

Comment: Thanks for all your responses. The problem turned out to be the ghostscript installation using homebrew on macOS, which was version 9.55. Once I removed that, the native gs installation (also v9.55) gave the correct result. Problem solved, although not sure what the difference was between the two installations of gs.

Comment: Indeed I cannot reproduce the problem with the Ghostscript that comes with MacTeX 2022, even though it's also version 9.55.0. I am quite surprised that the Homebrew version produces something different. To find out what the difference is, and whether there is an easy workaround that can be applied on the MaTeX side, can you post the output of `InputForm@MaTeX["."]`?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue with the Ghostscript included in MacPorts either, and I am not willing to install Homebrew just to try this, but if you can post the output that might be sufficient. I generally recommend the Ghostscript from here for Mac users: https://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/ This is the same as the one included in MacTeX, but updated more frequently.

Comment: Also, if you have time, it would be great if you could do the following: (1) Double-check that the issue was indeed Homebrew gs (2) Homebrew has gc 9.56.1 now, does this version still have the problem? (3) Post an answer here for other people who might be encounter the same problem, and I'll also add it to MaTeX's troubleshooting FAQ